# Synchronization of folders Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have shared a folder ubuntuone and I accepted. I go to panel ubuntuone, put synchronize that folder, put synchronize that folder, I can not find and synchronizable. Where do these folders are?

Comment: Your question seems a little unclear. Could you clarify more specifically what your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronised folders should be located in the same place (directory) among all computers where your Ubuntu One account is active.
For example, if I put the following folder `/home/vincenzo/mydocs/myphdthesis/` to Ubuntu One sync, then in all PCs (with the same login name), where I use my Ubuntu One account, I find all my files synchronised in the same location i.e. `/home/vincenzo/mydocs/myphdthesis/`.

Good luck.

Comment: I think what the OP did is **Share** a folder with themselves when they meant to **Sync** a folder. With Ubuntu One you can **Sync** a folder when you want the contents of a folder to be mirrored on all your Devices. You can **Share** a folder when you want to share a folder with another person who has an Ubuntu One account. A Share will show up in /home/vincenzo/Ubuntu One/Shared With Me.

Comment: Thank you for clarification :) I'd like to share some papers, so I will try to do so via Ubuntu One.